# Angular - Storing Recurring Days and Times and Getting Next Time

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime

I am working on a feature that will allow the user to store something similar to wake alarms. For example they might want MWF to run at 7:00 AM and 8:00 PM, and TTh to run at 6:00 AM and 9:00 PM.

I am struggling with finding an efficient format to store this data that will allow me to:

1. Present all the days/times set along with push/delete times.
2. Create a function that gets the next time in the list/array. With the times above if the function is called on Monday at 8:05 PM the function needs to return Tuesday at 6:00 AM.

I started by putting all the days/times in an array such as:

```
{
"0":["07:00","20:00"],
"1":["06:00","21:00"],
"2":["07:00","20:00"],
...
}
```

Where "0" represents `getDay()` for Monday. That made it easy to get the times for a day but seems a little messy in calculating the next time. My initial thought was to run a forEach() loop through the array and test the current day/time until I get the next time but that just seems like a horrible way to do it.

Any ideas on a better way to do this in angular or with a specific library?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.sortedIndex` of `lodash`.
See [here](https://lodash.com/docs/#sortedIndex).